# The error about string encryption scheduling : (char) (ch + key) % 26

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

Problem one: Here are two code spinner. Code A runs wrong. But I do not know what is wrong.

Problem two: code B is right.but I do not understand why it need to delete 'A’. then add 'A' after fmod. What is the effect about 'A'? Why it has the error after delete?

Code A (ch + key) % 26 )

Code B ('A' + ((ch -'A' + key) % 26))

```
 public void run() {    
        setFont("Arial-PLAIN-24");
        String line = readLine ("Enter line: ");
        int key = readInt ("Enter key: ");
        String siphertext = encryptCaesar(line , key);
        println("The result is: " + siphertext);
        String newplain = encryptCaesar(siphertext , -key);
        println("newplain:" + newplain);    
    }

    private String encryptCaesar(String str , int key){
        if(key < 0){
            key = 26 - ( -key % 26 );
        }

        String result = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            char ch = str.charAt(i);        
            result += encryptChar(ch,key);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private char encryptChar(char ch, int key){
        if(Character.isUpperCase(ch)){
            return ( (char) ('A' + ((ch -'A' + key) % 26)) );
        }
        return ch;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean that the code "runs wrong"? Please post a complete example which recreates the problem and describe precisely what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**'A'** is added to make sure the result of *"encryptChar"* method, is a valid character in ASCII range `64 to 90`, which is `A (CAPITAL) to Z (CAPITAL)`. Refer the ASCII table [here](http://www.asciitable.com/).

In your code subtracting of **'A'** can also be ignored. That is the below will also work,

```
('A' + ((ch + key) % 26))
```

Comment: Ofcourse this src wont work for key values between (Integer.MIN_VALUE + 89) and (Integer.MIN_VALUE -64) due to Overflow. But this is not related to OP's query.

Answer (score 0):

> **15.7.3 Remainder Operator %**
>
> ...
>   It follows from this rule that the result of the remainder operation
>   can be negative only if the dividend is negative, and can be positive
>   only if the dividend is positive.

An example is then provided:

```
int e = (-5)%3; // -2
int f = (-5)/3; // -1
System.out.println("(-5)%3 produces " + e +
                   " (note that (-5)/3 produces " + f + ")");
```

If the result of `((ch -'A' + key) % 26))` is negative, then wouldn't the result of `(char) ('A' + ((ch -'A' + key) % 26))` be some non-alphabet character? Perhaps you need to add 26 to any negative values or find the absolute value, so that they're positive and result in actual alphabet characters.